# Visible paragraph based on ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have button when i click on it i want to Visible the Paragraph using jquery CSS function.By Default Paragraph is in hidden mode.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
     $("p").css("visibility: visible");
  });
});
</script>
```

```
<p style="visibility: hidden;" id="P1">This is a paragraph1.</p>
<p style="visibility: hidden;" id="p2">This is a paragraph2.</p>
<p style="visibility: hidden;" id="P3">This is a paragrap3.</p>

<button>Click To show</button>
```

But this is not working i am interested to pass the value and based on the value i want to visible the particular paragraph.

```
var v=p2;
```

So when i click on the button and pass the value as "p2" i want to visible only paragraph second.

Comment: How exactly are you passing the value?

Comment: You have a typo: Its `.css("visibility", "visible")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in 3 way:-

***1st way:***

```js
function show(paragrapId) {
console.log(paragrapId);
  $("#"+paragrapId).css("visibility","visible"); //or can do .css({"visibility : visible"});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="visibility: hidden;" id="P1">This is a paragraph1.</p>
<p style="visibility: hidden;" id="p2">This is a paragraph2.</p>
<p style="visibility: hidden;" id="P3">This is a paragrap3.</p>

<button onclick="show('P1');">Click To show</button>
```

***2nd way:***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    show('p2');
  });
});

function show(paraID) {
  $('#' + paraID).css("visibility", "visible");//or can do .css({"visibility : visible"});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="visibility: hidden;" id="P1">This is a paragraph1.</p>
<p style="visibility: hidden;" id="p2">This is a paragraph2.</p>
<p style="visibility: hidden;" id="P3">This is a paragrap3.</p>

<button>Click To show</button>
```

***3rd way*** (but `id's` needs to be either lowercase or uppercase):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var id = randomIntFromInterval(1, 3);
    show('p' + id);
  });
});

function show(paraID) {
  $('#' + paraID).css('visibility', 'visible');
}

function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) { // min and max included 
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="visibility: hidden;" id="p1">This is a paragraph1.</p>
<p style="visibility: hidden;" id="p2">This is a paragraph2.</p>
<p style="visibility: hidden;" id="p3">This is a paragrap3.</p>

<button>Click To show</button>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply

Comment: @FresherProgrammer  glad to help you.. Happy coding..:)